# Delphi Indy NTLM on Windows 11 don't use good user

Tags: delphi, indy, ntlm, windows-11, delphi-11-alexandria

I have code that works well on Windows 10 and previous version and stop working on Windows 11. I use Indy with IdAuthenticationNTLM in my uses.

here is my code:

```
procedure SetIdHTTPSSL(AIdHTTP: TIdHTTP);
var
  ssl: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  ssl := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(AIdHTTP);
  ssl.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
  ssl.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
  ssl.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
  ssl.OnVerifyPeer := SSLIOHandlerVerifyPeer;
  ssl.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [sslvrfPeer];
  ssl.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 2;
  AIdHTTP.IOHandler := ssl;
end;

function IndyHttp(AFileName: string): Boolean;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  tmpString: string;
  FileStrm: TFileStream;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(Self);
  try
    IdHTTP.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
    IdHTTP.HTTPOptions := IdHTTP.HTTPOptions + [hoKeepOrigProtocol] + [hoInProcessAuth];
    IdHTTP.Request.Username := MyUserName;
    IdHTTP.Request.Password := MyPassword;
    IdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/octet-stream';
    IdHTTP.Request.CacheControl := 'no-cache';
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Content-Location: ' + ExtractFileName(AFileName));
    IdHTTP.Request.UserAgent := '';
    IdHTTP.Request.Accept := '';

    SetIdHTTPSSL(IdHTTP);

    FileStrm := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
    try
      tmpString := IdHTTP.Post(GetHTTPString, FileStrm);
      Result := pos('OK', UpperCase(tmpString)) > 0;
    finally
      FileStrm.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

When I check on Fiddler: the username sent on Windows 11 in the NTLM protocol is not MyUserName (that I set in my Indy components) but my Windows username. With older Windows version, it was ok.  What is the way to fix this?

Comment: IdAuthenticationNTLM implements NTLM from scratch, it is not dependent on the OS version, and has no concept of the Windows user. IdAuthenticationSSPI, on the other hand, uses OS APIs, and can use the Windows user.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I try both unit IdAuthenticationNTLM and IdAuthenticationSSPI and I notice this with the IdAuthenticationSSPI. In both case, I have 401 error on Windows 11 and works with older OS. Is there an implementation of negotiate protocol with Indy ?

Comment: I don't know why things would be working differently on Windows 11. IdAuthenticationSSPI is *supposed* to support `Negotiate`, but it [currently only uses NTLM](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/87).